# How to detect Linkedin Crawler accessing a web app

Tags: bots, linkedin-api

When links are shared via Linkedin, it seemingly triggers a bot to crawl that link.

What's the best way to detect that it's accessed by Linkedin on either the client or the server side? The user agent contains just a regular agent.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this issue on our site too, when sharing URL's in LinkedIn messenger, the device that opens the URL is just Windows/Chrome and missing the [LinkedInBot] tag on the user agent. Unfortunately the support have not been any help with this issue.

Instead we have to use an IP address checker (https://ip-api.com) and if the Org returned in the IP info payload is Microsoft then we are presuming that the link open was from LinkedIn.